# MySQL get records between / over above two date variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, between

I've got a MySQL question. I use Laravel in the examples below, but my question is rather MySQL related.

Assume I have an appointments table. An appointment can be of any duration.

So I have 2 appointments;

1. Appointment A: 2 March 2019 from 10am - 11am
2. Appointment B: 1 March 2019 from 11pm - 2 March 2019 9am

So; if I I search for records between 1 and 2 March - I will get 2 results. Something like, "where date <= 1 March AND <= 2 March"

Don't mind the command - its just an example.

My bottom line is that if I search for records between 1 and 2 March, I'll get the two appointments.

My question though; what if I have an event from 29 April to 4 March?

As an example;

1. Appointment A: 2 March 2019 from 10am - 11am
2. Appointment B: 1 March 2019 from 11pm - 2 March 2019 9am
3. Appointment C: 29 April 3pm - 4 March 4pm

So if I have two dates, and I say "WHERE date >= 2019-03-01 AND <= 2019-03-02" - then I would still get Appointment A and Appointment B.

But in reality, the space would be occupied because of Appointment C

How can I still search for records between 2 date variables - BUT a way to find Appointment C as well?

So, basically, when drawing / compiling my calendar, I would have my calendar sheet and see Appointment A and Appointment B - but I should see Appointment C as whole day events as well.

I don't want to selected all the appointment records from the database and sort them - I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Are `29 April` and `4 March` in the same year?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Time]
Imagine we have to find events that occur between t1 and t2. For example we have events that span between a1 and a2, b1 and b2 and c1 and c2.

According to what you say next formula will satisfy your request:

1. If event starts BEFORE requested t1, it has to end after t1
2. If event starts AFTER (or at t1), you need to check whether it starts before requested t2.

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE (start_date < t1 AND end_date > t1) OR (start_date >= t1 AND start_date < t2)
```

Here `t1` and `t2` are boundaries of requested range, `start_date` and `end_date` are columns that store corresponding data in MySQL.